# Should prepositions be repeated while joining multiple prepositional phrases?

Tags: conjunctions, prepositional-phrases, parallelism, repetition

1.Results indicated positive paths from A to B, B to C, and C to A and B.

2.Results indicated positive paths from A to B, from B to C, and from C to A and B.

Which of the above sentences is considered grammatically correct? Is it necessary to repeat "from" after the comma and/or the conjunction "and"?

I'd like to know what would be considered correct in American English, if it makes any difference.

Comment: They often make it easier to understand, and sometimes they resolve ambiguity.

Comment: It is good style to use *parallel constructions*.   Roughly, if you do a thing multiple times in a sentence, prefer to do it the same way.  https://www.skidmore.edu/writing_guide/terms/parallel.php

Comment: No, you do not need to repeat the preposition from

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically they are both fine.

The second one is longer to write, but is a little easier to read and understand.

One could even repeat the "to": "and from C to A and to B".